# Tests are not visible by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, xunit, dnx

My tests are not visible in visual studio 2015 with DNX46 (Test > Windows > Test Explorer)

I can run them from the console (with dnx test). Bellow the project.json of my test project

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "project Class Library",
  "authors": [ "me" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "NSubstitute": "1.9.2",
    "Search": "1.0.0-*",
    "Search.Infrastructure": "1.0.0-*",
    "Search.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "Swagger.Net.UI": "1.1.0",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
  }
}
```

I tried to install SideWaffle, maybe something was missing in my project, but same issue.

Comment: What DNX version do you use?

Comment: Not that :) Run "dnx --version"

Comment: Oh ok I tried with the final and 1.0.0-rc2-16249 (this the current used version)

Comment: Have you updated ASP.NET tooling to RC1?

Comment: Yep I executed AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe this is what you mean ?

Comment: Don't mix RC2 runtime and rc1 packages. They keeping them in sync

Comment: There is an asp.net version for rc2 ?
I changed the use for rc1-update1 but still the same issue (thank you for your patient and help, I appreciate) // I run dnvm use and changed in json project file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm the solution was to put the command after the dependencies declaration in project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "project Class Library",
  "authors": [ "me" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "NSubstitute": "1.9.2",
    "Search": "1.0.0-*",
    "Search.Infrastructure": "1.0.0-*",
    "Search.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "Swagger.Net.UI": "1.1.0",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to moving commands below dependencies, the command name should be 'test'. I had 'specs' and it wasn't working.